# Meteor.js upload folder on Production

Tags: node.js, meteor

So, we have built a file uploader in our application that is working on the local environment. We have the files being uploaded to public/upload and we can read the files using:

```
http://localhost:3000/upload/filename.extension
```

Now, when we move the code to production, we use a check:

```
getUploadPath = function () {
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var path = Npm.require('path');
    var devPath = path.join(process.cwd(),"../../../../../public");
    var prodPath = path.join(process.cwd(),"../client/app/");
    if (fs.existsSync(devPath)) {
        return path.join(devPath,"upload");
    } 
    else {
        return path.join(prodPath,"upload");
    }
}
```

Now, this saves the file to {prod_path}/programs/client/app/upload. However, I cannot use the file in the application. What's surprising is all the files that were in local seem to also be present in the same upload folder and are accessible by the application. What am I missing ?

Comment: I figured out that the program.json has the mapping for the path and the url. So, the next question is where do i store my static resources on the server for it to be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

If this application runs on server with Nginx or Apache, you can set /upload location, so files will be served directly without Meteor.

On Nginx I use something like this:

```
location /upload/ {
    root /home/app-name/bundle/programs/web.browser/app;
}
```